# javascript how to access array that has class labels

Tags: javascript

I have an object in javascript that contains an array. I am wondering how I can access the values using the class labels?
My object looks like this:

```
address_components: Array[8]
adr_address: "<span class="street-address">1808 N Clark St</span>, <span class="locality">Chicago</span>, <span class="region">IL</span> <span class="postal-code">60614</span>, <span class="country-name">USA</span>"
```

I want to get 60614 using `'postal-code'`. Sorry if this is a repeated question, was not able to find a solution, thanks.

Comment: Is your syntax correct?

Comment: You can't use unescaped `"` inside of a string delimited with `"`; either escape them or use `'` inside (or as delimiters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/bHq5H/)**</kbd>

Consider you have a string like this:

```
var adr_address = '<span class="street-address">1808 N Clark St</span>, <span class="locality">Chicago</span>, <span class="region">IL</span> <span class="postal-code">60614</span>, <span class="country-name">USA</span>';
```

Create an element on the fly, set the `innerHTML` of it to that string, and then get your `postal-code` element:

```
var adr_address = '<span class="street-address">1808 N Clark St</span>, <span class="locality">Chicago</span>, <span class="region">IL</span> <span class="postal-code">60614</span>, <span class="country-name">USA</span>';
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.innerHTML = adr_address;
var postal = elem.getElementsByClassName('postal-code')[0].innerHTML;
alert(postal); // 60614
```